# Pass model instance to django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have model A and model B. Thusly:

```
class A(models.Model):
     ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    ...
```

Now, a user makes an instance of `model A`, and from the detail page I want to allow them to click a link to create instances of `model B` that's attached to the `A` they just made. Is there an easy way for me to pass to the form for `model B` what instance of `model A` (the one the user is looking at) I want to attach it to? There is no reason for the user to know anything about it, and making a hidden field seems to be a bit of a hack, as does putting it as a get variable. Just wondering if there is a smoother way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, a user makes an instance of model A, and from the detail page I
>   want to allow them to click a link to create instances of model B
>   that's attached to the A they just made.

You are looking for [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets):

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets.
>   These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign
>   key.

The example from the documentation explains it better than I could:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
author = Author.objects.get(name=u'Mike Royko')
formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing such field as a hidden is a normal solution.

```
class BForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        widgets = {'a': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

And in **views.py** initiate this field with instance of A:

```
form = BForm(initial={'a': a})
```

This is not a hack but standard option.

Comment: This is not the right way to implement what you are trying to do.